# Python import local module, gives error if not executed on the repository path

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have a bunch of BitBucket repository that I have exported in the `~/.profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/francesco/Desktop/BitBucket/graphlan
export PATH=$PATH:/home/francesco/Desktop/BitBucket/hclust2
export PATH=$PATH:/home/francesco/Desktop/BitBucket/lefse
export PATH=$PATH:/home/francesco/Desktop/BitBucket/export2graphlan
```

Now the problem arise in the `export2graphlan` repository. In that repository I have, as sub-repository named `hclust2` that I import in the file `export2graphlan.py` with

```
path.insert(0, 'hclust2/')
from hclust2 import DataMatrix
```

The problem is, if I execute `export2graphlan.py` from `/home/francesco/Desktop/BitBucket/export2graphlan` everything is fine. When I lunch `export2graphlan.py` from anywhere else (since I exported it in the PATH) I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/francesco/Desktop/BitBucket/export2graphlan/export2graphlan.py", line 9, in <module>
    from hclust2 import DataMatrix
ImportError: No module named hclust2
```

Anyone have an idea what is wrong? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding on hclust2 an `__init__.py` file.

Every directory must have a `__init__.py` file.